# how to I add <a> id in wordpress menu for dashboard?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

How do I covert this html menu in wordpress menu and how do I enable `<a id="">`?

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="home" href="">???</a></li>
    <li><a id="description" href="">???</a></li>
    <li><a id="about" href="">?</a></li>
    <li><a id="shop" href="">????</a></li>
    <li><a id="blog" href="">???</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make a default wordpress menu code in `header.php`

```
<?php

if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' =>  'wpj-main-menu', 
        'fallback_cb' => 'wpj_default_menu')
    );
}
else {
    wpj_default_menu();
}

?>

add_action('init', 'wpj_register_menu');

function wpj_register_menu() {
    if (function_exists('register_nav_menu')) {
        register_nav_menu( 'wpj-main-menu', __( 'Main Menu', 'brightpage' ) );
    }
}

function wpj_default_menu() {
    echo '<ul>';
    if ('page' != get_option('show_on_front')) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. home_url() . '/">Home</a></li>';
    }
    wp_list_pages('title_li=');
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I also am trying to make `echo '<li><a id="home" href="'. home_url() . '/">Home</a></li>';`

But how I change those `<a>` id in dashboard?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Stop using id's everywhere

Answer (score 6):

Instead of ids you can add Classes to each item.

In menus within Wordpress back end you can select screen options and check the tick box for css classes.

You will then be able to add a unique class name to each menu item.

Your classes will add to the LI elements and then select links by doing

```
.home a {}

.description a {}

.about a {}

.shop a {}

.blog a {}
```

Comment: when i add those class those class is add on <li> Why not add <a>

Comment: please give any solution

Comment: hi, thanks for reply please see this static site http://kinkaku.co.jp/  you try to understand this <li class="home"><a>home</a></li>. I am so sorry i can't understand. I have no options with you. I try to fix this menu 1 days left.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: I fix this problem Thanks a lot Bobadew.